# Detect MySQL version or compile individually for installer?

Tags: mysql, windows, installation, drivers

I have a custom-built installer for our software and I'm in the process of upgrading/updating it to match our new program. The program works on a Server/Client model. When a new workstation is added as a client it has to install ODBC drivers to connect to the databases on the server.

My question is, should I be trying to connect to the server to get the version of MySQL to determine which drivers I need (3.5, 5.1, etc) by reading a registry key, or should I just compile separate installers for each version? What are the best practices for making installers for different environments?